# Converting Dialog to Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, dialog, bottom-sheet

I've an activity. After setting the Dialog Theme I'm able to make it as a Dialog.
I want to make it as a BottomSheetDialog. I want the dialog to be seen as bottom sheet and not a simple dialog.

Is there any way to startActivity directly as a BottomSheet?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of articles about HOW-TO with BottomSheetDialog, for example https://medium.com/glucosio-project/moving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295

Comment: I've gone through the article already. In this article I've an activity to show the dialog. What I want is to startActivity and it shows as a BottomSheet directly.

Answer (score 4):

First convert:

```
AlertDialog dialog =
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).customView(R.layout.dialog_my_loads_finish, false)
        .show();
```

to:

```
View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_my_loads_finish, null);
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(view);
```

and if you want to set specific height for bottom sheet you have to change `R.layout.dialog_my_load_finish` root to `CoordinateLayout` and add id and app:layer_behavior to first child
then:

```
 dialog.setOnShowListener(dialog2 -> {
  View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_question_confirm_ct);
  BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
  bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheet.getHeight());
});
```

finally: `dialog.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your layout file just below starting `Layout` (`LinearLayout/Relativelayput`)

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
```

**like :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
     app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
     android:id="@+id/sheetLayout"
     ...........>
     ..........
     ..........

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Java file

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet= new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
View sheet = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheetLayout, null);
bottomSheet.setContentView(sheet);
bottomSheet.show();
```

Comment: What about `setContentView()` of the activity? As even that is using `R.layout.sheetLayout`

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Activity layout. Your Activity can inflate different layout through `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.