# How to animate BottomSheetDialogFragment in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, bezier, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` that I would like to animate by applying Bézier curve on its entry and exit.
I have managed to apply simple animation this way

> ```
> override fun onActivityCreated(arg0: Bundle?) {
>     super.onActivityCreated(arg0)
>     dialog?.window?.attributes?.windowAnimations = R.style.BottomSheetDialogAnimation
> }
> ```

where the style is

> ```
> <style name="BottomSheetDialogAnimation">
>     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/bottom_sheet_slide_up</item>
>     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/bottom_sheet_slide_down</item>
> </style>
> ```

but I'm stuck how to do it with Bézier curve animation.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896605/how-to-apply-easing-animation-function-on-view-in-android get you most of the way there? Because I suspect you don't want a Bezier curve, but instead of clean easy in/out behaviour. However, if you do explicitly need an actual Bezier curve, updating `getInterpolation` to calculate the [bezier values](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#explanation) would be trivial.

Answer (score 4):

onActivityCreated is **Deprecated** so you can use **onViewCreated**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog!!.window!!.attributes.windowAnimations = R.style.BottomSheetDialogAnimation
    }
```

NOTE: Comment or Remove **onActivityCreated** method.

Comment: Thanks Tippu but the point of my question to find a solution for Bézier curve animation.

Answer (score 1):

To control or customize the animation of a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, you must set the `windowAnimations` attribute at the end of `onCreateDialog()`.

```java
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706883/converting-dialog-to-bottom-sheet
    View dialogLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, null);
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(dialogLayout);

    // Example of setting a button click listener
    Button button1 = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Control or customize the animation of the BottomSheetDialog here
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.BottomSheetDialogAnimation;

    return dialog;
}
```

There is no easy way to apply a Bézier curve to the animation. The closest you can get is to use `"@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"` or `"@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"` in the animation XML file. These will gradually slow down or speed up the animation near the end.

**res/anim/bottom_sheet_slide_up.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">

    <!-- Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232372/slide-a-layout-up-from-bottom-of-screen -->
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="75%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="500"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```